# How to build and modify source code locally of a package from Hackage using the `Haskell Stack`?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

### Background

I downloaded the source files of package (e.g. `test-framework`) to have a closer look in it's architecture, to modify it for experiments, and may be to contribute later on.

I downloaded the source code and got stuck in incompatibilities and lots of compiler errors.

### Question

Is there a step by step procedure, of how to obtain the source code properly and to setup such a project using the Haskell Stack?

Answer (score 1):

### Procedures

We can choose out of the following two opportunities:

- without use of tarball files
- with use of tarball files

#### Procedure - without use of tarball files

Thanks to the "Cigarette Smoking Man"...

1. Setup your main project
2. unpack the package that should be obtained as source code

   `stack unpack`
3. change current directory to the created folder

   `cd <package>`
4. initialise the folder (creates file `stack.yaml`)

   `stack init`
5. modify `stack.yaml` of the main project, to add package with relative path to section `packages`!!!
6. modify `package.yaml` of main project, to add dependency to package with constraint (e.g.  `== 1.2.1`) to section `dependencies`
7. delete cabal-file (here `Test6.cabal`), if any
8. in the main folder build the main project
   `stack build`

NOTE: This setup can be even used in ghci, by typing `stack ghci` and `:reload`.

#### Procedure - with use of tarball files

1. Setup your main project
2. unpack the package that should be obtained as source code

   `stack unpack`
3. change current directory to the created folder

   `cd <package>`
4. initialise the folder (creates file `stack.yaml`)

   `stack init`
5. generate a tarball file of the package code

   `stack sdist`
6. modify `stack.yaml` of the main project, to add package with relative path to section `extra-deps`!!!
7. modify `package.yaml` of main project, to add dependency to package with constraint (e.g.  `== 1.2.1`) to section `dependencies`
8. delete cabal-file (here `Test6.cabal`), if any
9. in the main folder build the main project
   `stack build`

### More detailed procedures

For more details check source:
[Building a package locally from source using "stack"](https://www.sw4sd.com/hasksheet/doku.php?id=toolsetup:buildingapackagelocally)

### Example projects

Additonally, for both alternatives, here you can find a complete projects, where the module `Random` exports an additional function.

GitHub:

[Test7 - without use of tarball files](https://github.com/JoergBrueggmann/Test7)

[Test6 - with use of tarball files](https://github.com/JoergBrueggmann/Test6)

Comment: After `stack unpack` you can point to the local version of the package by adding its path to stack.yaml's `packages` section -- to use *it* instead of the hackage (stackage) version. Also, hpack/package.yaml, although a popular tool, isn't required for this, just the .cabal file is.

Comment: An easy way to test changes to the package is to run `stack repl` instead of `stack build`, then modify the package, then `:reload` the repl to load the changes.

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan, thank you. Very helpful. Eventhou, I don't fully understand, yet. In particular, I don't understand the first comment. Likely lack of my knowledge. Is this an alternative method? If yes, what is the benefit?

Comment: After you run `stack unpack test-framework` you get a folder in your current directory with the code for that package. So instead of creating a tarball and adding its path to `extra-deps` of your main project, you can just add the path to the folder itself to the `packages` section in your main project's stack.yaml like so: `packages: [./test-framework]`. After that, if you run `stack repl` in the main project you can go and change the code for the package and run `:reload` to reload the changes immediately.

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan, now it is much clearer. I will try that. What is `:reload`? It looks like a ghci command to me? Do you mean run `stack exec ghci` and then `:reload`?

Comment: Yes, it is in ghci, but you need `stack repl` (= `stack ghci`) because then the stack tool runs ghci specially by bringing the stack project into scope (when running a bare ghci, then ghci wouldn't know about your stack project, it's dependencies, etc).

Comment: There is a difference between `stack ghci` and `stack exec ghci`: the latter "won't load up locally written modules for access" (https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#ghci-the-repl), so `stack ghci` fits better.

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan, thank you! I tested it. That's even better.